# Pgfplots jump mark error when plotting a floor function

Tags: pgfplots, pgfmath

For some weird reason the following code gives me the wrong plot

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
 \addplot+[jump mark left,samples at={2.5,5,...,20}] {floor(x/2.5)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: the resulting plot]

Clearly, at for instance `x=15`, y should equal to 6. Is this a bug?

**Added:** I've noticed that the `floor()` function is superfluous in this case - the `jump  mark left` option works just like a floor function, which produces the correct graph. Still, this does not justify the above erroneous example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd guess that this is a floating point rounding error (even though `\pgfmathparse{floor(((5-2.5)*6)/2.5)}\pgfmathresult` correctly prints 6.0). Calculations done using TeX's dimensions have poor precision. One way to fix it is to add a small number to the argument of floor:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
 \addplot+[jump mark left,samples at={2.5,5,...,20}] {floor(x/2.5+0.0001)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Comment: I agree with the solution - here is just a small footnote for the understanding:

The `\pgfmathparse` experiment is not quite complete -- you need to call `\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu}` before evaluating the expression to reproduce the behavior of pgfplots. In that case, it returns 5.9999 as result of 15/2.5.

Note that the `...` syntax in `samples at` might also introduce rounding errors.